# after adding text and image over a video. the output of video quality looses

Tags: android, ffmpeg

i am using ffmpeg for adding image and text over image. the command works fine but video loses quality. how to retain quality of video.

```
   String  imgcmd[]=new String[]{"-i", videopath ,"-i", imgpath,"-filter_complex", "[1]scale=720:1280[b];[0][b] overlay=main_w-overlay_w:main_h-overlay_h,drawtext=text="+text+":fontcolor=#FFFFFF:fontsize=18:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)-145:fontfile="+fontpath ,  "-preset" ,"ultrafast","-codec:a", "copy",output};


   public void LoadFFmpegLibrary()
     {
    if(ffmpeg!=null)
    {

        try {
            ffmpeg.loadBinary(new LoadBinaryResponseHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onStart() {
                    Log.e("ffmpeg","Start to load");
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure() {
                    Log.e("ffmpeg","failed to load");
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {

                    imageprogressDialog=  

  ConstantClass.ShowProgressDialog(VideoRecordingActivity.this,"Loading");
                    imageprogressDialog.show();
                    SharedPreferences 
        sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("shared",MODE_PRIVATE);
                    String 
      imgpath=sharedPreferences.getString("imgpath","");
                    String 
    fontpath=sharedPreferences.getString("fontpath","");
                    String  
      videopath=sharedPreferences.getString("videopath","");
                     //"-crf" ,"24"0
                    String  imgcmd[]=new String[]{"-i", videopath ,"-i", 
        imgpath,"-filter_complex", "[1]scale=720:1280[b];[0][b] 
       overlay=main_w-overlay_w:main_h- 
       overlay_h,drawtext=text="+text+":fontcolor=#FFFFFF:fontsize=18:x= 
       (w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)-145:fontfile="+fontpath ,  "-preset" 
         ,"ultrafast","-codec:a", "copy",output};

                    ImageCommand(imgcmd);

                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {

                }
            });
        } catch (FFmpegNotSupportedException e) {
            // Handle if FFmpeg is not supported by device
            Log.e("ffmpeg",e.toString());
        }
    }
}





  public void ImageCommand(String command[])
{

    ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(VideoRecordingActivity.this);
    try {
        // to execute "ffmpeg -version" command you just need to pass "-version"
        ffmpeg.execute(command, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                Log.e("ffmpeg","Exaction Start");
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgress(String message) {}

            @Override
            public void onFailure(String message) {
                imageprogressDialog.dismiss();
                Log.e("ok",message);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String message) {
                imageprogressDialog.dismiss();

                Toast.makeText(VideoRecordingActivity.this,"Video Edited Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                PlayVideo();
                playvideo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                imageprogressDialog.dismiss();
                Log.e("ffmpeg","Exaction Start");
            }
        });
    } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
        imageprogressDialog.dismiss();
        Log.e("ffmpeg",e.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: i am using media recorder for record video and in that the resolution of video 1280*720.

Comment: commmand works fine video is best quility

Comment: post both videos so that i can fing problem in command

Comment: hii vinesh bro..thanks for your comment.... video quality was good it works fine....that was my mistake not any command

Comment: but bro i have question. i have 30 sec video and at the of  end of video i want to add some line like( wake up early , sleep early) in linear format how can i do that using ffmpeg..like youtube end of video they shows some useful information... please help

Comment: send you help soon

Comment: thanks for Res. waiting for res.

Comment: hii vinesh bro.. i m stuck at one point can you help me... i am creating video using 2 image  but  take almost 5 6 min or more some times it no work can you help where is wrong in my command or how to improve speed of video editing in ffmpeg

Comment: String imagetovideocmd[]={"-framerate", "1/2" ,"-i", inputputimg ,"-r" ,"25", "-pix_fmt" ,"yuv420p", output};                                                                              
  String inputputimg="/storage/emulated/0/FestiveApp/Assets/frame%2d.png";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this answer is regarding your comment you ask question for add  text at end of the video like youtube videos has. here is a command execute and let me know

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i 1.jpg -f lavfi -t 5 -i color=#000000:s=1280x720 -filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=main_w-overlay_w:main_h-overlay_h,drawtext=text="text":fontcolor=#FFFFFF:fontsize=18:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)-145[video];[2]drawtext=text="FINAL_VIDEO_TEST":fontcolor=#FFFFFF:fontsize=50:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)-145[textOverlay];[video][textOverlay]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0" -preset ultrafast -codec:a copy mvm/testOut.mp4
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195960/discussion-on-answer-by-vinesh-chauhan-after-adding-text-and-image-over-a-video).